# Problema com hook em ReacNative

Tags: react, react-native

Estou iniciando meus estudos em ReactNative e estou tendo dificuldades com um exercício que criei para treinar o uso do hook `useState`.

Eu basicamente criei o seguinte componente `Contador.js`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Text, Button } from 'react-native'
import Estilo from './estilo'
 
export default ({ inicial = 0, passo = 1 }) => {
    [numero, setNumero] = useState(inicial)
 
    const inc = () => setNumero(numero + passo)
    const dec = () => setNumero(numero - passo)
 
    return (
        <>
            <Text style={Estilo.txtG}>{numero}</Text>
            <Button title="+" onPress={inc} />
            <Button title="-" onPress={dec} />
        </>
    )
}
```

E chamei o mesmo duas vezes no meu `App.js`:

```
import React from 'react'
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native' 
 
import Contador from './components/Contador'
 
export default () => (
    <SafeAreaView style={style.App}>
        <Contador inicial={100} passo={13} />
        <Contador />
    </SafeAreaView>
)
 
const style = StyleSheet.create({
    App: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: 20
    }
})
```

Quando eu clico nos botões da segunda instância do componente o incremento e decremento ocorrem normalmente no `Text` da segunda instância, até aí tudo bem.

Mas por algum motivo, quando clico nos botões da primeira instância do componente, o incremento e decremento são exibidos no `Text` da segunda instância do componente, e não do primeiro.

Alguém poderia me dizer porque?

Comment: Isso aqui `[numero, setNumero] = useState(inicial)` está incorreto! Deveria ser `const [numero, setNumero] = useState(inicial)`. Fora isso, não parece ter nada de errado com seu código, analisando superficialmente.

Comment: Olá amigo, resolveu o problema... Obrigado. 

Mas porque será que não declarar como const gerou esse problema?

Comment: Primeiro, eu já fiquei surpreso de não ter dado erro pelo fato de declarar variáveis sem `var`, `const` ou `let. Segundo porque provavelmente `numero` se tornou uma variável global.

Comment: Como já foi apontado o problema pelo @CmteCardeal, deixo o link para a pergunta que responde o porquê disso acontecer